# Numpy shuffle rows then sort by one column only

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, shuffle

I have a record array with values such as these:

```
[(1, 3.0)
 (1, 5.0)
 (2, 4.0)
 (2, 7.0)
 (3, 9.0)
 (3, 3.0)]
```

I need to shuffle the rows and sort the array by the first column. A desired output would be:

```
[(1, 5.0)
 (1, 3.0)
 (2, 7.0)
 (2, 4.0)
 (3, 9.0)
 (3, 3.0)]
```

I tried to first shuffle using `numpy.random.shuffle(someArray)` which worked as expected with a result like the following:

```
[(3, 3.0)
 (1, 5.0)
 (2, 7.0)
 (1, 3.0)
 (2, 4.0)
 (3, 9.0)]
```

but then when i sorted using `someArray = numpy.sort(someArray, order=['firstColumn'])`, the result was the first array, sorted by first and second column as well. It is as if i used `order=['firstColumn', 'secondColumn']`.

Comment: When you show a structured array like this, include the `dtype` information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) on 1st column and specify `mergesort` as type of sort. Then use the returned indices to sort the original array:

```
>>> a
array([(3, 3.0), (1, 5.0), (2, 7.0), (1, 3.0), (2, 4.0), (3, 9.0)], 
      dtype=[('1st', '<i8'), ('2nd', '<f8')])
>>> i = np.argsort(a['1st'], kind='mergesort')
>>> a[i]
array([(1, 5.0), (1, 3.0), (2, 7.0), (2, 4.0), (3, 3.0), (3, 9.0)], 
      dtype=[('1st', '<i8'), ('2nd', '<f8')])
```